# My upper radiator hose is never pressurized but car never over heats....?

Tags: radiator, heat, pressure, hose

I'm stumped, it doesn't effect the car and no overheating or mechanical issues. Lower one is pressurized but not the top? 06 Impala police package. Do the police versions have bigger radiators and coolers?

Comment: How do you know the upper radiator hose doesn't carry higher-than-ambient pressures? Have you measured it? Similarly, is there are repair/maintenance question here? Does it concern you that you believe it's unpressurized?

Comment: Well, I did pressure test the coolant system with same results. No pressure.

Comment: How are you testing for pressure in the upper radiator hose?

Comment: Attaching the pressure tester to the radiator neck and pressurizing the system. Hose isn't leaking or in bad shape. (No store sells these hoses as they are police package) The upper one goes directly into the engine so I'm guessing it carries the coolant into the engine and lower one circulates it

Comment: If you are only reading pressure at the radiator cap, then you aren't necessarily reading the pressure of the upper radiator hose. I ask because I actually can't think of a convenient way to specifically measure it. Also, you have it backward. The upper radiator hose received hot coolant from the engine and feeds the radiator. If the upper hose feels warm after driving, it's doing its job. Also, I don't really see how this is a maintenance/repair question, so I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Furthermore I think if the thermostat is closed there shouldn't be pressure? I could be very wrong though

Comment: The pressure in a closed system will be the same at all points unless there is a pressure regulator fitted (or, a mix of fluids at different densities, but that is usually small and not relevant to this). So, have you fitted two pressure gauges or fitted the gauge at two points to provide comparative readings? Or, are you just squeezing the hose by hand.

Comment: I squeezed the hose and also put a pressure tester on the radiator cap.Thermostat seems fine because the car goes to normal operating temp (stuck open) and doesn't over heat (stuck closed) maybe that's just how the upper hose was designed to work?

Comment: @Hari Ganti the OP is asking about a behavior in his vehicle that he believes is not correct.  How is that off-topic? We allow even theoretical questions about engines. This seems very on-topic to me.

Comment: @cdunn There's no clear statement of a vehicle problem. If there were signs of overheating or a blocked radiator/coolant line, I'd agree. Simply squeezing the coolant line is not a good test. Also, depending on how the system is configured, pressurizing the radiator cap *may not* pressurize the upper radiator hose. Furthermore, a 15psig radiator cap wouldn't feel much different than an unpressurized line. This question is asking about a problem that doesn't seem to exist. The OP *has not* measured pressure in the upper radiator hose.

Comment: All true, but none of which makes this off-topic. Seems like this would be a good discussion to move to meta. I didn't disagree with anything you said, except that this is off-topic. The OP not performing a test correctly does not make it off-topic. There is a clear statement of what the OP a believes is a problem. Whether it is or not is the open question, but the OP believes there's an issue. And hence it's on-topic.